# accelerometer in Android emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app in Android which implements accelerometer to detect the shaking
of the real device. But i am having problems to test it in emulator. Is emulator supports accelerometer, so that developers can test such kind of application in emulator.
I don't know is it possible or not.. though i have tried in find some clues but dint get success yet. If any body knows please help me..