# Can we test shake application on android emulator?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accelerometer in Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859353/accelerometer-in-android-emulator)

I have an application that plays music when the user shakes his phone, can I test it on the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with it, but i've seen this being adviced before, and it seems to me that it does the trick:

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

(emphasis mine:)

> The OpenIntents SensorSimulator lets
>   you simulate sensor data with the
>   mouse in real time. It currently
>   supports **accelerometer**, compass,
>   orientation, and temperature sensors,
>   where the behavior can be customized
>   through various settings